# HTML/CSS - Zooms in on select tag when tapped on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I have a select menu with options.

When I'm on a mobile device I tap this menu, it slightly zooms in on it. Is there a -webkit property or something that is causing this?

How do I change it so that it doesn't zoom in on the screen when the select menu is tapped?

Please see the gif below.

[image]

```
<select class='example'>

  <option>Example</option>
  <option>Example</option>
  <option>Example</option>
  <option>Example</option>
  <option>Example</option>
  <option>Example</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some mobile phones and tablets behave this way when interacting with form elements. Adding this meta tag to your `<head>` should resolve your issue:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0" />
```

Here is a detailed explanation on what this does and why it works:
https://thingsthemselves.com/no-input-zoom-in-safari-on-iphone-the-pixel-perfect-way/